# For every binary number x, is there a power of 3 beginning in x?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I noticed that for the binary number $k=(1,10,11)$, $3^k$ begins with the digits of k. That relationship immediately breaks down, but it doesn't seem hard to find a power of 3 beginning similar to any binary number.  E.g., $3^2$ starts with 100, $3^4$ starts with 101, etc.

Is this actually the case? Can every binary number be found at the start of some power of 3?

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with notating binary numbers as ordered triples. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I believe they were just writing down the binary representations of 1, 2, 3, and then making an observation about something that holds for these representations.

Comment: @Mark Ah, I see. Perhaps a better way way to phrase this would be, “. . . for a binary number $k\in\{1,10,11\}$, one has that $3^k$ begins with the digits of $k$.” (Obviously the “one has that” part is unnecessary, but I dislike separating mathematical expressions with only punctuation.)

Comment: Would it be clearer if I amended it to say something like "The binary representation of $3^k$ begins with the same digits as the binary representation of k when k=1, k=2, or k=3"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  For each finite binary string starting with $1$ there is an interval $[a,b) \subset [0,1]$ such that $3^n$ begins with that string iff the fractional part of $\log_2(3^n)$ is in that interval.  But because $\log_2(3)$ is irrational, the fractional parts of $\log_2(3^n) = n \log_2(3)$ are dense in $[0,1]$.